# Making sense of coordinate systems in retrieved data from a CSW

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, extents, csw

I am invoking a CSW server (Catalog Service for the Web) and I am trying to draw the bounding box of each record in the front end of my application.

One of the problems is that the coordinate system of the bounding box is not always in EPSG. What I recieve is something like this:

```xml
<ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326" dimensions="2">
    <ows:LowerCorner>-1.7 -10.3</ows:LowerCorner>
    <ows:UpperCorner>5.4 5.1</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:BoundingBox>
```

So the coordinate system information is condensed in a string like this:

```
urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326
```

But this string does not always make sense. For instance, sometimes I recieve strings like this:

```
urn:ogc:def:crs:::Lambert Azimuthal Projection
```

Is there a way to transform these coordinate system identifiers into WKT (well known text)? Doing so one can programmatically assign a coordinate system to these strings.

Comment: Do you know what the server is? Because the 2nd one is probably a bug

Comment: Yes, the second comes from a geonetwork server. The first from a geoserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OGC URNs are defined and described in [OGC Document 07-092r1](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=24045), the first one you have encountered is telling you that your data is in EPSG:4326 as defined in version 6.11 of the EPSG database (that is lat,lon).

The second one looks like either a major bug in GeoNetwork or (more likely) a user data input issue where some one has typed "Lambert Azimuthal Projection" into a box that was expecting an EPSG numeric code.

Comment: Thank you very much! The link you provide explains how to extract all the parameters necessary to understand the coordinate system
``urn:ogc:def:objectType:authority:version:code:value1:value2``